Why is there an offset between grey bars and width of arrows in upper limits
For the image shown below, which shows upper limits in red arrows between two variables X and Y and on the right side there is Z axis showing value of grey bars, why is their an offset between grey bars and width of arrows.

The complete code for the plot is shown here:
def plot(Xmin, Xmax):
    
    datafile = ''  # Placeholder for the data file path

    try:
        data = np.loadtxt(datafile)
        xmin = data[:, 0]
        xmax = data[:, 1]
        yvalue = data[:, 2]
        yerror = data[:, 3]
        zvalue = data[:, 4]
        upperBound = data[:, 5]

        # Compute the midpoint of the x-axis
        x = np.sqrt(xmin * xmax)
        xerr = np.array([x - xmin, xmax - x])

        # Compute y-axis values
        y = x**2 * yvalue / (xmax - xmin)
        yerr = x**2 * yerror / (xmax - xmin)
        y_ul = x**2 * upperBound / (xmax - xmin)
        y_ulerr = np.array([0.5 * y_ul, [0] * len(y)])

        # Create the plot
        fig, ax = plt.subplots()

        # Plot the data points where z > 9
        ax.errorbar(x[zvalue > 9], y[zvalue > 9], xerr=xerr[:, zvalue > 9], yerr=yerr[zvalue > 9], 
                    fmt='.k', color='blue', label='Detected', markersize=12)

        # Plot upper limits where z < 9, in red
        ax.errorbar(x[zvalue < 9], y_ul[zvalue < 9], xerr=xerr[:, zvalue < 9], yerr=y_ulerr[:, zvalue < 9], 
                    fmt='.k', color='red', uplims=True, label='Upper Limit', markersize=12)

        # Set axis limits and scales
        ax.set_xlim(a,b)
        ax.set_ylim(c, d)
        ax.set_xscale('log')
        ax.set_yscale('log')

        # Set axis labels with bold font
        ax.set_xlabel(r'X [units]', fontweight='bold')
        ax.set_ylabel(r'Y [units]', fontweight='bold', fontsize=9)

        # Plot z-values on a secondary axis
        ax2 = ax.twinx()
        ax2.bar(x, zvalue, width=(xmax - xmin), color='gray', edgecolor='gray', alpha=0.5)
        ax2.set_ylim(bottom=0)
        ax2.set_xscale('log')
        ax2.set_ylabel('Z value', fontweight='bold')

        # Return the file paths (placeholders)
        return png_file, pdf_file

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

I was expecting that there won't be any offset between grey bars and width of arrows in red. Is it related to geometic mean? or is there some bug in matplotlib plotting. I tried using arithmetic mean and there is no offset there. What could be the reason for this problem?

Welcome to SO. Please take a look at How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example so that users can better understand and reproduce your problem.

A logscale x-axis can be tricky for alignment. Probably you need the bar plots with align='edge' and use the arithmetic mean to position the error bars. Please add some dummy test data to create a reproducible example.  If it is a bug, a reproducible example can be used to open an issue at GitHub.

Thanks for your response. Using arithmetic mean the position does align, but why is it not working with geometric mean, even with align = 'edge' . The data for the above code is at https://github.com/siddhantmannaiith/data

Even with align = "edge" we don't get them in center.
